# Batch script to zip a folder using InfoZip

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy, zip

i'm a near complete beginner to batch scripting.

I'm currently learning how to create batch files. My goal is to compress a folder using exclusively InfoZip, add the date to the file name, and have that file copied to an USB memory stick plugged on H:\
The reason why i need to use InfoZip, even though it is a very old program, is because i need somthing that works even on Win95.
InfoZip is not installed, it is just unpacked in folder and ready to use.

It is possible to download InfoZip 3.0 from here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/infozip/

Anyway, so far, the only thing i could come up with is this...

### --------------------------------------

Title : Your folder will be zipped into an archive that will be copied on the USB memory stick plugged on your computer. Please DO NOT remove the memory stick during the operation.

@ECHO OFF

call d:\infozip\wiz.exe

pause

### --------------------------------------

It just brings up the InfoZip window on the screen, but then i have absolutely no idea about how to make it zip a folder, add the date, and copy that zipped file to the USB.

All the regular commands meant for 7-zip or Winzip don't seem to work with InfoZip.

I could really use some help, please :)

Thanks!

Comment: Read the documentation of InfoZip!

Comment: There's no general answer to this since it does not depend on batch files or any standard. It's specific to the program you're using, the only answer you can have will be in this program's documentation (website, forum). Just a hint : try to call it with a parameter such as -h or --help, it's usually the best way to discover the basic console functionnalities of a program.

Comment: Thank you, will try this right now.

Answer (score 3):

Using the waybackmachine I was able to get the documentation for info-zip:

https://web.archive.org/web/20170829173722/http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zip.html#EXAMPLES

In contrary to what zip.exe shows, the syntax for zipping files is this:

```
zip -r zipfilename zipfilecontents
```

Example:

```
zip -r myzip.zip c:\myfolder\*.*
```

The -r parameter includes subfolders as well.

Problem is that the complete folder structure is included in the zip. I have not found a solution for this yet.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the structure folder problem, add a cd command that will target the folder container which has inside your file or files. This before running the code proposed by Martien de Jong upside.

for example:

The path of my file is: `cd C:\aa\B\file.txt`
So the path you will put in the cd to target the folder container is: `cd C:\aa\B`

---

```
cd C:\aa\B

zip -r myzip.zip B\*.*
```

*Remember that this code will zip all the files included in B folder.